# find a document by an uknown index of an array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

This is a `mongoDB` document , i am having trouble finding documents by an specific index value of the `"Fields"`

```
    {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5726f5e8516876b3a4f65d9b"),
    "Title" : "The Art of Problem Posing",
    "titleurl" : "the_art_of_problem_posing",
    "attrs" : {
        "Publisher" : "Psychology Press; 3 edition (December 9, 2004)",
        "Author" : "Stephen I. Brown"
    },
    "authurl" : "stephen_i_brown",
    "Rating" : 1,
    "Reviews" : [
        {
            "reviewer" : "Orion",
            "review" : "cbv",
            "time" : "Tue May 03 2016 14:39:17 GMT+0600 (BDT)",
            "_id" : ObjectId("572863b52d72f3947606bcce")
        }
    ],
    "Links" : [
        {
            "url" : "https://www.google.com",
            "provider" : "Orion",
            "description" : "gg",
            "_id" : ObjectId("572863a92d72f3947606bccd")
        }
    ],
    "authurls" : [ ],
    "Subfields" : [ ],
    "Fields" : [
        "Study & Teaching",
        "Mathematics"
    ],
    "__v" : 0
}
```

How can i find all those documents that has `"Mathematics"` inside `"Fields"`

Comment: `db.collection.find({"Fields": "Mathematics"})`

Comment: well, this is embarrassing! i tried that, didnt work then. Now its working, may b i typed something wrong :p . And Thank you :)